# Responsive Website Design - Set Text & Scalable Image

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive website design and would like to use a set text size next to a scalable image size. I.e. if the user enlarges the page the image will enlarge, but the text next to it will always stay the same size. The problem I have is that I am telling '.inforight' to be 68%, but when the page gets smaller that 68% then goes over the text. I'm sure there's a solution for this, but i'm new to responsive website design and am struggling to understand how to do it.

```
<div class="infoleft">    
<h2>Test Header</h2>
<p>Test Writing.</p>
</div>

<div class="inforight">   
<a class="anchor" id="website"></a><img style="width: 100%; height: auto"; src="images/jcb/website.jpg"> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.infoleft {
width: 986px;
padding-left: 0px;
float: left;
color: #777777;
padding-top: 0px;
display: block;
position:fixed;
top:180px;
}


.infoleft p {
font-size: 9pt;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 20px;
width: 230px;
}

.infoleft h2 {
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #DBD9D4;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
width: 230px;
font-size: 11pt;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
color: #ea5310;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.inforight {
width: 68%;
padding-right: 55px;
float: right;
padding-top: 45px;
}  


.inforight img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up responsive codes is a bit difficult on your own. Mistakes may creep up like the case here.

I'd suggest you look into a responsive framework like bootstrap. It has a very good documentation as well at: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can always use media queries to set the design like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.inforight {
width: 96%;
}
}
```

to change the orientation of page and place thing the way they look good but you have to set the design to your accordance

Comment: Thank you. I am using media queries for iPad / iPhone sizes etc, but since this really adjusts as the user scrolls their screen, i'll be using a lot of media queries to try and keep the scale consistent with the text.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I managed to resolve it by adding set px paddings to both the right and left margins. This means it will stay within a found area, but still scale within that, which is what I needed. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Please update this and set this as the right answer.